# How can I make square-connect work with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, square-connect

Basing myself on the example provided by the SquareUp documentation (https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples.git). I am trying to integrate squareup to process payments with CC but I do not know what happens.

the view:

```
  <div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
  <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3"></h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md" >
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading font-bold">CC info</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="no-boot" ng-controller="PaymentController" ng-cloak>
            <div id="successNotification" ng-show="isPaymentSuccess">
              Card Charged Succesfully!!
            </div>

            <form novalidate id="payment-form" ng-hide="isPaymentSuccess">

              <div id="card-errors" ng-repeat="error in card_errors">
                <li>{{error.message}}</li>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Card Number</label>
                <div ng-model="data.card.card_number"  id="sq-card-number"></div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>CVV</label>
                <div ng-model="data.card.cvv"  id="sq-cvv"></div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Expiration Date</label>
                <div ng-model="data.card.expiration_date"  id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Postal Code</label>
                <div ng-model="data.card.postal_code"  id="sq-postal-code"></div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <input ng-click="submitForm()" ng-disabled="isProcessing" type="submit" id="submit" value="Buy Now" class="btn btn-primary">
              </div>

            </form>

              <button id="sq-apple-pay" class="button-apple-pay-block" ng-show="supportApplePay"></button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
  // signin controller
app.controller('PaymentController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    //for showing #successNotification div
    $scope.isPaymentSuccess = false;

    //for disabling payment button
    $scope.isProcessing = false;
    //for disabling apple pay button
    $scope.supportApplePay = false;

    $scope.data = {
      product_id: "001",
      user: {},
      card: {},
      products: {
        "001": {
          "name": "Paper Origami 1:10,000 scale model (11 inch)",
          "value":"1.0",
        },
        "002": {
          "name": "Plastic 1:5000 scale model (22 inch)",
          "value":"49.0",
        },
        "003": {
          "name": "Metal & Concrete 1:1000 scale replica (9 feet)",
          "value":"5000.0",
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function(){
      console.log($scope.data)
      $scope.isProcessing = true;
      $scope.paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
      return false
    }


    var cardNumber = $scope.data.card.card_number = 5409889944179029;
    var cvv = $scope.data.card.cvv = 111;
    var expirationDate = $scope.data.card.expirationDate = '02/21';
    var postalCode = $scope.data.card.postalCode = 3311;

    $scope.paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
      applicationId: 'sandbox-sq0idp-IsHp4BXhhVus21G5JPyYpw',
      locationId: 'CBASECJCvmqtoIL1fn3iReEjQRcgAQ',
      inputClass: 'sq-input',
      inputStyles: [
          {
            fontSize: '14px',
            padding: '7px 12px',
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
          }
        ],
      cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: '5409889944179029',
        value: '5409889944179029'
      },
      cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: '111',
        value: '111'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: '04/21',
        value: '04/21'
      },
      postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: '33114',
        value: '33114'
      },
      applePay: {
        elementId: 'sq-apple-pay'
      },
      // cardNumber:''+cardNumber,
      // cvv:''+cvv,
      // expirationDate:''+expirationDate,
      // postalCode:''+postalCode,
      callbacks: {
         cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
          if (errors){
            $scope.card_errors = errors
            $scope.isProcessing = false;
            $scope.$apply(); // required since this is not an angular function
          }else{
            $scope.card_errors = []
            $scope.chargeCardWithNonce(nonce);
          }

        },
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
          // Alert the buyer
        },
        methodsSupported: function (methods) {
          console.log(methods);
          $scope.supportApplePay = true
          $scope.$apply(); // required since this is not an angular function
        },
        createPaymentRequest: function () {
          var product = $scope.data.products[$scope.data.product_id];
          return {
            requestShippingAddress: true,
            currencyCode: "USD",
            countryCode: "US",
            total: {
              label: product["name"],
              amount: product["value"],
              pending: false,
            }
          };
        },
        // Fill in these cases to respond to various events that can occur while a
        // buyer is using the payment form.
        inputEventReceived: function(inputEvent) {
          switch (inputEvent.eventType) {
            case 'focusClassAdded':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
            case 'focusClassRemoved':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
            case 'errorClassAdded':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
            case 'errorClassRemoved':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
            case 'cardBrandChanged':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
            case 'postalCodeChanged':
              // Handle as desired
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    $scope.chargeCardWithNonce = function(nonce) {
      alert("no");
      var url = "libs/php_payment/process-card.php";

      var data = {
        nonce: nonce,
        product_id: $scope.data.product_id,
        name: $scope.data.user.name,
        email: $scope.data.user.email,
        street_address_1: $scope.data.user.street_address_1,
        street_address_2: $scope.data.user.street_address_2,
        city: $scope.data.user.city,
        state: $scope.data.user.state,
        zip: $scope.data.user.zip
      };
      $http.post(url, data).success(function(data, status) {
        if (data.status == 400){
          // display server side card processing errors
          $scope.isPaymentSuccess = false;
          $scope.card_errors = []
          for (var i =0; i < data.errors.length; i++){
            $scope.card_errors.push({message: data.errors[i].detail})
          }
        }else if (data.status == 200) {
          $scope.isPaymentSuccess = true;
        }
        $scope.isProcessing = false;
      }).error(function(){
        $scope.isPaymentSuccess = false;
        $scope.isProcessing = false;
        $scope.card_errors = [{message: "Processing error, please try again!"}];
      })

    }

    //build payment form after controller loads
    var init = function () {
       $scope.paymentForm.build()
    };
    init();

  }]);
```

> error: "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: I think you are totally missing the point of `$scope$apply()`;  It's not "required since this is not an angular function", it is "required when something else updates the DOM without angular's knowledge.".  None of these functions do that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done angular in a while, but I'm betting that your issue is in:

```
   methodsSupported: function (methods) {
      console.log(methods);
      $scope.supportApplePay = true
      $scope.$apply(); // required since this is not an angular function
    },
```

You are calling `$apply()` after a non-asyc call, generally you apply new data that you got asynchronously. See [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog)